# Silverlight, can I access DOM elements in Webbrowser control?

Tags: .net, silverlight, browser

I need to automate a browser in a Win/OSX app, and I'm trying out if Silverlight could be my tool.
In a pure .NET WebBrowser control I have full access to the DOM elements, but it seems that this is not the case for the Silverlight Webbrowser control. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do, and what isn't working? You can control much of the environment via Silverlight -- I've done a bit of DOM element minipulation with Silverlight, but nothing really heavy.

Comment: This is an OOB app?  The Web content to be manipulated is downloaded from the same site as the application Xap?

Comment: Yes, an OOB app, that will open any URL, and manipulate the DOM of these websites.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate DOM inside a page which hosts you silverlight app you can use

`HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("mainDiv");`

Comment: irrelevant. the question ia about accessing DOM of the document loaded into WebBrowser component in Silverlight application