# How can I open an iframe on the asp page behind my Silverlight 4.0 Application without it being visible

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, iframe, mvvm

My application uses MVVM architecture and needs to occaisonally call some outside asp pages to interact with a few other systems. The problem is I that I really don't want the user to see these pages because they don't have a UI, they really just need to open in the background, perform their function, then close, all without ever being seen. I can not use windowless mode. The URL that I need the frame pointing to is generated in the viewmodel so I also need to know how to get that info to the frame. I'm really lost on this issue as there isn't much online related to doing this without windowless mode. Any help would be much appreicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See these two for references in how I pieced the code together for this.

[Silverlight, can I access DOM elements in Webbrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514117/silverlight-can-i-access-dom-elements-in-webbrowser-control)

http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=700

Note that the only thing you can do is set the value of the url for that frame if it is in a different domain because of security reasons. That may be fine for you. So try something like:

```
var element = HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("yourIframe");
element.SetAttribute("src", yourUrl);
```

Comment: Well when I try that src is not a property of the object. The code doesn't know that it is an iframe. Any ideas?

Comment: doh.. forgot it was an HtmlElement returned, you have to call SetAttribute. See the above edit.